# Is it neccessary to update git branch before merging it to develop / master?

Tags: git, git-merge

Consider a scenario in which I have created a branch from master called "Feature 1". My friend also created a branch from master called "Feature 2". He finished his code changes and merged "Feature 2" branch back to master.

Now I have completed my changes in "Feature 1" branch and want to merge back to master ( which has been updated since I branched of it ). Do I need to pull / rebase before I can merge "Feature 1" to master or is that something git will handle?

Comment: If there are no conflicts it should merge fine. I prefer doing a rebase before merging since it makes the history look better imo. If you are using GitHub it will have a message indicating if it can be merged without conflicts.

Comment: I have seen one case where after merging "Feature 1" branch without rebase / pull resulted in having a file that should not had been there in the master branch. There was no conflict while merging "Feature 1" to master.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's not necessary to update your master branch before you merge your feature branch into it.  However, that is not the best practice.  You are better off doing the following:

1. Pull master branch and sure it is up to date with your remote.
2. Merge/rebase your master branch into your feature branch
3. Fix any merge conflicts
4. Merge your feature branch into master

Doing it this way will ensure that your commits are the most recent in the history and that any merge conflicts are handled on the feature branch, not the master branch.  This keeps your master branch clean and your history cleaner.  The other people using your repo will be happy.

The commands will look like this:

1. git checkout master
2. git pull --rebase origin master
3. git checkout feature1
4. git rebase master
5. *fix any conflicts*
6. git checkout master
7. git rebase feature1  // will rebase with no conflicts since you fixed them previously.

To elaborate on what each command will do:

1. jump to your version of `master`, which is outdated
2. pull changes from repo and update `master`, applying any local changes `master` has on top (none, if you used branches for edits)
3. jump back to your `feature1` branch that's still based off the outdated "master"
4. apply `feature1` changes on top of `master`, which was updated in #2
5. *fix conflicts*
6. jump back to `master`, which is updated but still without your `feature1` changes
7. apply `master` changes on top of `feature1`, but since feature1 is a direct child of master, this just updates master again with your feature1 changes
8. here you should consider `git push` to "publish" your changes to master to the repo

Comment: shouldn't step 7 be `git merge feature1`?  the merge should be a fast-forward after steps 1-6.

Comment: Yes step 7 should be git merge feature1 followed by git push origin master.

Comment: can you elaborate on "The other people using your repo will be happy."

Comment: My thinking on this has evolved over time, especially when you work on highly active repos that have many contributors. Some of this is personal and organizational preference, rather than a rule that must be followed. In general, when viewing git history, it's easier to understand if the history is linear. So, if you are working on smaller repos, it's generally better to do a rebase to avoid merge commits. Highly active repos, adding merge commits might be the only way to get your changes in when the `main` branch moves quickly.

Comment: step 7 git rebase feature1 , i don't recommend use rebase on master branch ,since rebase will rewrite the history ,rebase only works on feature/bugfix branch